# Selecionando gaps em base de dados

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Estou tentando montar um select que localize os itens faltantes de uma base de dados. Isso é super incomum, 'selecionar' os itens que não existem. rsrs  Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela chamada TBL795 com a coluna NRBEM que deveria, em tese, não ter
lacunas na sequencia dos itens cadastrados.

Deve ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os números cadastrados estão em sequencia.

Se estiver assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esta errado, pois alguns itens não foram cadastrados.

Numa tabela com milhares de itens fica difícil você verificar por select se esta faltando algum item e quais são os itens faltantes.

Uma das maneiras seria criar uma tabela TESTE:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE ( 
  NRBEM VARCHAR(15))
```

alimenta-la com o comando:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE 
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt A
```

e executar o select

```
SELECT A.NRBEM FROM TESTE A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B 
ON A.NRBEM = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
```

eu vejo todos os itens que estão faltantes em minha tabela.

Já que o comando:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE
      cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
    SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt
```

cria uma tabela virtual em memória eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte select:

```
SELECT NRBEM FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B
ON A.NRBEM = B.NRBEM
```

Mas não funciona.

Assim

```
SELECT X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X <100000) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
```

**QUASE** funciona, ou seja, não dá erro. Mas **não traz** os itens faltantes, traz todos os dados da tabela virtual.

**Resumo**: não tem como eu fazer esse select com essa 'tabela' virtual, sem ter de cria-la fisicamente e alimenta-la?

Eu lembro de ter feito algo parecido com isso, mas agora não sei onde esta aquele select. :(

Comment: Eu postei a pergunta, mesmo tendo achado a resposta um pouco antes. Pensando em ajudar alguém e recebo votos negativos. Francamente.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas acho que ficou um pouco confusa sua pergunta. Ajudar é legal, mas pra isso poderia deixar um pouco mais claro o que vc quer. Além disso, a solução proposta depende um pouco de fé, pois não tem nenhuma explicação de como funciona. Fico um pouco com receio de comentar essas coisas, pq as vezes é mal recebido, mas acho que seriam pontos que se melhorados, poderiam valorizar as duas postagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes mesmo de postar a questão eu descobri onde estava errando. Postei porque pode ser útil para mais alguém.

Eu precisava transforma minha coluna em numero para selecionar os dados corretamente.

Isso funciona.

```
SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X <100000) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) AS NRBEM FROM TBL795 ) B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
```

Assim fica melhor:

```
SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X < ( select max( cast ( nrbem as number )) from tbl795 )) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) AS NRBEM FROM TBL795 ) B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
```

Se eu quiser consultar quais as plaquetas faltantes entre os itens de 2400 a 2700

```
SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(2400) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X < (2700)) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) AS NRBEM FROM TBL795 WHERE NRBEM >= 2400 and nrbem <= 2700 ) B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
LIMIT ( 2700 - 2400 + 1 )
```